# How to display all software name using MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

This is database value. I have no idea how to query MySQL to display the pattern I want. The table store all software name and their version in software 1,2,3 and version 1,2,3..I want to display all software name in one query.

[image: database]

Comment: What's an example output you wish to generate?

Comment: Can you post an example query you have tried

Comment: In my sql query i want to search software name from coloumn Software 1- n no.s in return output will be matching ip address to the software name in terms.

Comment: I tried this query "select * from demo where software2 = '$name'"

Answer (score 1):

You can try with -

```
$sql = "Select * from tablename";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$softwares = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $softwares[] = $result;
}

foreach ($softwares as $sw) {
    $cols = count($sw);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cols; $i++) {
        if (!empty($sw['software'.$i])) {
            echo $sw['software'.$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Fetch, loop and print as you need.

Comment: using HTML page when enter particular software name then display there ip addresss in php how to do..

Comment: Just get the value and fetch the data.

Comment: Connect php with html page. in html have two box one is text box for entering software name and another is submit button. when enter software name and click on submit button then display that ip address.

Comment: Without code it is not possible. Please add your code first.